# Error when installing cocoapods - Host is down

Tags: cocoapods

i had some problems installing a gem, so i tried updating cocoapods. I uninstalled it first, then tried installing it again with command sudo gem install cocoapods and gem install cocoapods. This won't work because i had following error:

*error: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EHOSTDOWN)
Host is down - sendto(2) for "8.8.8.8" port 53*

This happens when i do gem install cocoapods and sudo gem install cocoapods. Any idea why this happens ? my connection to internet is ok. I already tried searching on the internet for possible solutions but couldn't find a similar one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind, i was using little snitch which blocked my incoming connection :)